# Prove that the spacetime interval is not invariant under Galilean transformations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, galilean-relativity

The spacetime interval $(\Delta s)^2 = (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 - c^2(\Delta t)^2$ is invariant under the Lorentz transformation and this isn't the case for the Galilean transformation. As the title might suggest, I have tried to prove that the spacetime interval is not invariant under Galilean transformations. I will try to explain what I have done and I wonder what's wrong with my proof.

In my attempt to prove that $(\Delta s)^2$ isn't invariant under Galilean transformation I wrote $(\Delta s)^2$ as $(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 + (z_2 - z_1)^2 - c^2(t_2 - t_1)^2$ and fully expanded it as

$-c^2 t_1^2+2 c^2 t_1 t_2+c^2 \left(-t_2^2\right)+x_1^2-2 x_1 x_2+x_2^2+y_1^2-2 y_1 y_2+y_2^2+z_1^2-2 z_1 z_2+z_2^2$

I then reasoned that if $(\Delta s)^2$ really *were* invariant during a Galilean transformation $(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 - c^2(\Delta t) = (\Delta x')^2 + (\Delta y')^2 + (\Delta z')^2 - c^2(\Delta t')$ must hold true.

I applied the same principle as before and wrote $(\Delta x')^2 + (\Delta y')^2 + (\Delta z')^2 - c^2(\Delta t')^2 = 
(x'_2 - x'_1)^2 + (y'_2 - y'_1)^2 + (z'_2 - z'_1)^2 - c^2(t'_2 - t'_1)^2$

Then, the Galilean transformation

$\begin{cases}t' = t \\ x' = x - v_x t \\ y' = y - v_y t \\ z' = z - v_z t\end{cases}$

was applied and I substituted terms in

$(x'_2 - x'_1)^2 + (y'_2 - y'_1)^2 + (z'_2 - z'_1)^2 - c^2(t'_2 - t'_1)^2$

into

$\left((x_2 - v_x t) - (x_1 - v_x t)\right)^2 + \left((y_2 - v_y t) - (y_1 - v_y t)\right)^2 + \left((z_2 - v_z t) - (z_1 - v_z t)\right)^2 - c^2 (t_2 - t_1)^2$

Again, I expanded the expression

$-c^2 t_1^2 + 2 c^2 t_1 t_2 - c^2 t_2^2 + x_1^2 - 2 x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 + y_1^2 - 2 y_1 y_2 + y_2^2 + z_1^2 - 2 z_1 z_2 + z_2^2$

Remember, I reasoned that $(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 - c^2(\Delta t) = (\Delta x')^2 + (\Delta y')^2 + (\Delta z')^2 - c^2(\Delta t')$ must hold true and now we have an expanded from for both sides, one being the spacetime interval in a "rest frame" $S$ and the other the spacetime interval for the same events in $S'$. If we compare them, we find that they are equal to each other:

$(\Delta s)^2_S = -c^2 t_1^2+2 c^2 t_1 t_2+c^2 \left(-t_2^2\right)+x_1^2-2 x_1 x_2+x_2^2+y_1^2-2 y_1 y_2+y_2^2+z_1^2-2 z_1 z_2+z_2^2$

$(\Delta s)^2_{S'} = -c^2 t_1^2 + 2 c^2 t_1 t_2 - c^2 t_2^2 + x_1^2 - 2 x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 + y_1^2 - 2 y_1 y_2 + y_2^2 + z_1^2 - 2 z_1 z_2 + z_2^2$

Since they are equal, $(\Delta s)^2_S = (\Delta s)^2_{S'}$ and the spacetime interval *is* invariant under Galilean transformations.

**What's wrong with my proof?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because check-my-work questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: As a hint... does $x_1 - x_2 = x_1' - x_2'$ make sense if $t_1\neq t_2$?

Comment: @Timaeus I went with how the question was framed (as per the last sentence), rather than with the precise contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that to *disprove* something, you only need one counterexample. So I'd simply advise: don't bother with the symbols: choose a simple example. Think of the events at $X_1=(t,\,x,\,y,\,z)=(0,0,0,0)$ and $X_2=(t,\,x,\,y,\,z)=(1,0,0,0)$. The proper time between them is 1. Now transform to co-ordinates boosted in the $x$ direction by speed $v_x=1/2$. Using the Galilean boost, we have $X_1^\prime = X_1$, $X_2^\prime  = (1,\,-\frac{1}{2},\,0\,0)$ and the proper time between them is now $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. *quod erat non demonstrandum*

Comment: Really? I get the spacetime interval $-(-0.5)^2+1^2 = 0.75$. What do you get $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ from?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver We're talking the same language. You've calculated the metric element $(\Delta s)^2$ and I've calculated the proper time $\tau = \Delta s$.

Answer (score 1):

You just correctly showed that a Galileian "transformation" where $v_x=v_y=v_z=0$ "preserves" the interval.

You were supposed to find two Galilean frames and two events where the two frames compute different intervals. You didn't even pick two frames since you let $v_x=v_y=v_z=0$.

Comment: Where do I assume that?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver You introduced $v_x$ and such then used it once and then it disappeared, so you set it equal to zero. Things that aren't zero don't disappear and you never said it was non zero.

Comment: Well, I put `Expand[FullSimplify[((x2 - vx*t) - (x1 - vx*t))^2 + ((y2 - vy*t) - (y1 - vy*t))^2 + ((z2 - vz*t) - (z1 - vz*t))^2 - c^2 (t2 - t1)^2]]` into Mathematica and got back `-c^2 t1^2+2 c^2 t1 t2-c^2 t2^2+x1^2-2 x1 x2+x2^2+y1^2-2 y1 y2+y2^2+z1^2-2 z1 z2+z2^2`.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver But why would you type that into Mathematica? And why wouldn't you be alarmed that the velocity dropped out? None of those things with the v are the primed coordinates. They are just translated unprimed coordinates so you just picked a different origin.

Comment: Well, Mathematica just does the algebra so much faster and without error. Wait, how can't they be the primed coordinates?

Comment: And I never said that $v_x = v_y = v_z = 0$, so why does Mathematica cancel the v's out? Is Mathematica wrong on simple algebra?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver They aren't the primed coordinates because you brought up a new variable that wasn't in the problem. The Problem should have x1 x2 y1 y2 z1 z2 t1 t2 vx vy vz and if you see anything else in your formula then you just threw in a random variable for no reason. You randomly moved your origin in the direction of the velocity by some random amount. And that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver You didn't say they weren't zero. And them being zero is the only way the things you wrote could be correct. Since you just translated the points by a random multiple of $(v_x,v_y,v_z)$ that could only be equal to the transformation in the case when they are zero. Mathematica cancelled it because translating your origin by a random multiple of a fixed vector doesn't change the distance. And Mathematica apparently doesn't ask you to initialize new variables so doesn't warn you when you introduce random scalings.

Comment: Substituting $t$ with $(t_2-t_1)$ should fix it? I did that, but it still didn't give me any terms with v's.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver What fixes it, is to understand what you are doing. That replaces a new random variable t with a some new random combination of old variables. You could replace t with t2cosine(t1/t2) but why do that when it would only equal the primed version when the velocity is zero. If you want a nonzero velocity then you need to actually write down for instance $x_1'$ using the transformation for a nonzero velocity.

Comment: Isn't $x_1' = x_1 - v_x (t_2-t_1)$?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver And to be clear I keep saying the velocity is zero because it is the only way the thing you write can be a transformation. Mathematica is dropping it out because you told Mathematica to translate the origin randomly (which a velocity zero transformation, to just change the origin).

Comment: @MarkusKlyver 'Isn't $x_1' = x_1 - v_x (t_2-t_1)$?' Ask yourself what $x_1$ is and ask yourself whether the value of $t_2$ affects what the value of $x_1'$ and please don't write down random formulas and ask if they are correct. This is not a homework help site and I'm not supposed to check your work we should talk about physics related concepts.

Comment: So it recognizes that I'm doing transformations, and treats my expression as such?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver No. You are wrote down the formula for a situation where you randomly translated the origin for no reason. And then when I pointed it out, you proposed a different random translation in the same direction but by an amount that **might** be different but since the first one was random it could actually be the same. I don't know why you want to randomly translate your origin. But that is what you are asking Mathematica to compute, so that's what it does and Mathematica correctly tells you that a random translation of the origin doesn't change the interval between events.

Comment: I begin to see what you are trying to say. $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ are just shifted $v_x (t_2-t_1)$, making $\Delta x$ the same.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver Correct. And that is a kind of zero velocity transformation that is allowed. But it's an allowed zero velocity transformation in Lorentzian relativity and also in Galilean Relativity too.

Comment: But then, what did I do wrong? I used the transformation and substituted accordingly.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver Do an example. Pick actual numbers and by hand compute what the primed numbers should be. If you know what it means to change to a moving frame you should be able to compute it.

Comment: Well, I find that both $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ are shifted by $v_x (t_2-t_1)$. I've tried with real numbers.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver I have trouble believing you. Rod Vance's example is quite simple and he already did the math for you. Did you follow it?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver Here is a hint. You should be able to compute $x_1'$ before you even know what $t_2$ is.

Comment: Just one note, he uses $X_1$ and $X_2$ to denote the events, not the individual $x$ coordinates. He gets ${X_2'}_x = {X_2}_x - v_x *(t_2 - t_1) = 0 - 0.5(1-0) = -0.5$, just as the transformation says.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver If his $t_1=0$ then it is your imagination that he computed it that way. And then I have zero idea how you think he computed the x component of the first event.

Comment: I believe ${X_1'}_x = X_1' - v_x t = 0 - 0.5 \cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver You can't believe that. That equation has a random symbol, $t,$ sitting in the middle of an equation that otherwise could have physical meaning. And that's ignoring mere sloppiness in having two primes and treating a vector and a component with the same symbol and all that. You still just bring up a random $t$ for no reason instead on doing a transformation. maybe you don't know what a nonzero velocity transformation looks like. If you wanted to learn physics concepts you could study that or even ask a new question about that. A straight up transformation, nothing about intervals

Comment: Oh, I messed it up. ${X_1'}_x = {X_1}_x - v_x t = 0 - 0.5 \cdot 0 = 0.$

Comment: The $t$ comes from the transformation $x' = x - v_xt$.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver That formula doesn't have any 1 or 2. Why is that?

Comment: Why should it have ones and twos?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver You claim to have "used" it to get some formulas that have a random $t$ symbol and also have some 1s and maybe 2s too (no one knows what you are doing). So how did that happen? How did you use a formula without a 1 or a 2 and get the equation with the random symbols?

Comment: I have already explained what I'm getting $t$ from: the transformation. I'm not sure why you call it a random symbol. $x' = x - v_xt$. Also, I don't recognize the 2 at all.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver There is no t in the original problem just x1 x2 y1 y2 z1 z2 t1 t2 and then you brought up vx vy and vz. There is no t. In the transformation you don't have any 1 or 2 and I asked why you don't and you ignored me. And I gave you a hint that you should be able to transform one event without someone telling you some second event.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver I call t a random symbol because you bring it up out of nowhere. And when I harass you over and over again you sometimes say the value of t magically depends on t2 as if whenever you try to transform some event 1 you get stuck and can't do it until someone randomly picks one of the infinitely many other events for you and then you randomly use it somehow for no known reason to do no one knows what with it. Because what should t2 have to do with x1 or x1' anyway?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver If you understood how to do a frame transformation I should be able to give you an x1 t1 and vx and you should be able to compute x1' without any more information. If you can't then your new question for yourself should be about that.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver: $t$ is the random symbol. $t_1$ and $t_2$ are not random symbols. If you're getting a "naked" $t$ then you have screwed up. Furthermore, if $x_1'$ depends on $t_2$ or $x_2'$ depends on $t_1$ you have screwed up. There exists one way to do $x' = x - v_x~t$ that avoids all of these pitfalls, can you see what it is? (Hint: it is a simple relabeling of the terms in that equation.) Can you then understand why everything else you're doing has been **physically** wrong, as in it does not perform a Galileian transformation but rather a coordinate translation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30388/discussion-on-answer-by-timaeus-prove-that-the-spacetime-interval-is-not-invaria).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is buried somewhere in "if we expand them then we find out that they are equal to each other." So if we map $(t, \vec r) \mapsto (t, \vec r - \vec v~t)$ we find $\Delta t \mapsto \Delta t,\; \Delta \vec r \mapsto \Delta \vec r - \vec v~\Delta t$ where the operator $\Delta$ takes a symbol $U$ and transforms it into $U_2 - U_1.$

Therefore, $(\Delta \vec r)^2 - c^2 (\Delta t)^2 \mapsto (\Delta \vec r - \vec v~\Delta t)^2 - c^2 (\Delta t)^2,$ and it is not very hard to expand the right hand side to find:$$(\Delta  \vec r)^2 - c^2 (\Delta t)^2 - \Delta t \Big[2 \vec v\cdot\Delta\vec r - \vec v\cdot\vec v ~\Delta t\Big],$$which is obviously not equal to $(\Delta \vec r)^2 - c^2 (\Delta t)^2$ unless $\Delta \vec r = \vec v~\Delta t~/2.$

Comment: No, the problem is not getting an $x_1'$ or an $x_2'$ correctly.